# Rotating surface in z axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-3dplot

I have the following code to plot a surface:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-4,,zmax=5,zmin=-2,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4,axis lines=center,view={150}{20}]
\node [right] at (axis cs:6.2,0,0) {eixo-$x$};
\node [above] at (axis cs:0,6.2,0) {eixo-$y$};
\node [above] at (axis cs:0,0,5.1) {eixo-$z$};
    \addplot3[surf,faceted color=teal,color=teal,opacity=0.5,fill opacity=0.2,opacity=0.5,domain=0:2,y domain=0:360,samples=40]
    ({x*cos(y)/sqrt(0.4)}, {1+x*sin(y)}, {x^2-1});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to rotate this surface 30 degrees considering the projection on xy plane. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This rotates the plot about the z-axis. The rotation angle is `alphar`. Depending on your conventions you may need `-30`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-4,,zmax=5,zmin=-2,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4,
axis lines=center,view={150}{20},declare function={alphar=30;
    fx(\x,\y)=\x*cos(\y)/sqrt(0.4);fy(\x,\y)=1+x*sin(\y);}]
\node [right] at (axis cs:6.2,0,0) {eixo-$x$};
\node [above] at (axis cs:0,6.2,0) {eixo-$y$};
\node [above] at (axis cs:0,0,5.1) {eixo-$z$};
    \addplot3[surf,faceted color=teal,color=teal,opacity=0.5,fill opacity=0.2,opacity=0.5,domain=0:2,y domain=0:360,samples=40]
    ({cos(alphar)*fx(x,y)+sin(alphar)*fy(x,y)}, 
    {cos(alphar)*fy(x,y)-sin(alphar)*fx(x,y)}, {x^2-1});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]